# Can't install Ubuntu 18.04 on USB with persistence on mac

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, usb, live-usb, macosx

I have tried so many times to get persistence working on my Ubuntu USB using macosx(Dual-Boot), but none of them work. I followed all the steps correctly, including how to format my USB drive, but I just can't get persistence to work on it. Ubuntu is so cool and want to use but nothing gets saved because it is not persistent. Please help me in getting the correct method on installing Ubuntu on a USB drive with persistence using mac.

**P.S.** These are the following attempts on Ubuntu:

1) normal installation using Unetbootin (off course it is not persistent)

2) using syslinux and Unetbootin(USB didn't show up in boot loader)

3)Trying to get Mac Linux USB loader working with github and xcode but didn't work even after following the ReadMe file (I can't buy the software cuz I am a student not allowed to buy things online using a credit card)

Thanks for helping me btw.

I have watched numerous videos as well and I am no professional in this field, so I have nervously followed many youtuber's videos and not done anything personally by me.

Comment: Does your Mac boot from a **cloned** live system, when you have cloned from the iso file to the USB pendrive? In that case, does it boot in UEFI mode or BIOS mode (I would guess in UEFI mode, but I am not sure, because I have no Mac computer). If you have two USB pendrives, you can make a cloned live Ubuntu system in one of them, boot from it, install [**mkusb**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and use it to create a persistent live system in the other USB pendrive. Such a persistent live system can boot both in UEFI and BIOS mode (depending on how the computer is booted).

Comment: First off, thanks for replying! Yes, i do boot in UEFI mode (atleast im pretty sure!), and i will try mkusb. So it basically installs ubuntu on it? BTW i want it completely installed, so ubuntu knows it is(Ignore the last sentence if it makes no sense). Thanks!

Comment: Do you want Ubuntu installed like into an internal drive, but into a USB pendrive or USB SSD (faster)? In that case, please see this link, [How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/942312#942312)

Answer (score 0):

First, remember Macs and Linux are funky. Sometimes, a live USB made on one Mac will not work on another .

As a person who has used Mac Linux USB Loader regularly, I have found this to be your actual best possible step by step instructions:

- Go to 7/11
- Buy a prepaid Visa or Mastercard with the correct amount of money on it
- Bring it home and buy MAC Linux USB Loader
- If it doesn't work right after you buy it, email the guy for support, and he's super happy to help

Here's what you do if you decide you want  to install Linux on the Mac  using the USB.

Installing Linux on a Mac is kind of a pain, but the basic steps are

1. make your partitions using the recovery disk version of Disk Utility in Mac
2. use the live USB to install Linux on the Linux partition
3. then reinstall OS X

If you have OS X installed on the box, even if it's a very small partition, you still have mac Linux USB loader if you need to remake a live USB

This should make it so you boot directly into Linux, and can use the alt option menu to boot into OS X.

If it boots into OS X first after this type of install, start over. If it's booting into OS X first, it will not boot into Linux.

Switch it around to see if there's a different order you need to install stuff.